# How do I pass a variable from a custom module to its template file?

Tags: theming

I need to know the simplest method to pass variable from custom module to its template file. 
I have created the custom.module and placed custom.tpl.php in the module folder.

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => t('custom!'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_page() {

    $setVar = 'this is custom module';
    return theme('custom', $setVar);    
}
```

i have added theme function but it is not working, can any one suggest me what is wrong with this code

```
function theme_custom($arg) {
  return $arg['output'];
}

function custom_theme() {
  return array(
    'Bluemarine' => array(
        'variables' => 'output',
        'template' => 'Bluemarine',
     ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Independently from the Drupal version for which you are writing the module, there are two errors in your code:

- You define "Bluemarine" as theme function, but then you call `theme('custom')`, which would call the "custom" theme function
- If you define "custom" as a theme function that uses a template file, then `theme_custom()` is never called

If you are writing code for Drupal 6, then the code should be similar to the following one. I take the assumption the name for the theme function is `custom`.

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => t('custom!'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom' => array(
      'arguments' => array('output' => NULL),
      'template' => 'custom',
     ),
  );
}

function custom_page() {
    $output = 'This is a custom module';
    return theme('custom', $output);    
}

function theme_custom($output) {
}
```

The template file will have access to `$output`, and to any variables set in `template_preprocess_custom()`, if your module implements it.

For example, you could implement code similar to the following one:

```
function template_preprocess_custom(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['output'] == 'This is a custom module') {
    $variables['append'] = ' and I wrote it myself.';
  }
}
```

With this code, the template file has access to `$output` and `$append`.

As example of theme function that uses a template file, you can look at [theme_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_node/6), which is defined in [node_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_theme/6), and that uses [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/6) as template file; the preprocess function implemented by the Node module for that theme function is [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6).

Comment: Thanks Kiam, obviously missed OP's first comment about using D6. +1

Comment: Thanks Kiam, template_preprocess_custom(&$variables) did the trick

Comment: Now I want to move tpl to theme folder, how can i do that?

Comment: @KamranAkhter That is a different question. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the wrong theme function. Instead of `function theme_custom` it should be `function theme_Bluemarine`. You also need to pass an array to the variables piece of [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).  See a simple example [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7#comment-14989).

Using your example (after changing template and theme function to `custom`):

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => t('custom!'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_page() {
  $setVar = 'this is custom module';
  return theme('custom', array('output' => $setVar));
}

function custom_theme() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom');
  return array(
    'custom' => array(
        'variables' => array('output' => null),
        'template' => 'custom',
     ),
  );
}
```

Now in custom.tpl.php just need `<?php print $output; ?>`

Comment: Thanks for reply the example u gave is node module and i have non node module.i just need a way to pass variable to tpl file, i m using drupal 6.plz help

Comment: Thanks for reply, it is giving me the error No such file or directory actually it is expecting the file custom.tpl.php in the module folder which i already have so in code bluemarine will be replcaed by custom. Bluemarine is the drupal theme which i m using.

Comment: changed the above code and giving me the white blank screen what should i do plz help

Comment: I changed the code, and I have it working on my site.

Comment: I just copy paste the above code but it does not work

Comment: Need more details than "it doesn't work". Is there an error? Do you have a custom.tpl.php file in the module's directory? Did you navigate to example.com/custom ?

Comment: No Error. custom.tpl.php and custom.module in sites\all\modules\custom folder. yes navigate through example.com/custom, it is showing me the title custom which is defined in custom_menu()

Comment: The code reported in this answer is for Drupal 7, while the OP is interested in an answer for Drupal 6. (See his first comment. The Drupal version should have been reported in a more prominent place, but this isn't an issue, since a question that doesn't make clear what version the OP is using can have answers for different Drupal versions.)